# GStreamer "Changing the `location' property on filesink when a file is open is not supported."

Tags: python, gstreamer

I got tasked to work with GStreamer and after dealing with several different issues, I've tried quite a bit to figure out what's going wrong. There are many issues I'm currently facing, but one that has me scratching my head harder than anything is that I am unable to change the file location of a filesink after setting the sink state to NULL or READY without getting a warning.

```
** (python3:12542): WARNING **: Changing the `location' property on filesink when a file is open is not supported.
```

Now, here's a minimal snippet of code that shows what I'm doing to make this error happen:

```
    self.sink.set_state(Gst.State.READY) # have also tried NULL
    self.muxer.set_state(Gst.State.READY) # have also tried NULL

    self.sink.set_property('location', output_file)

    self.muxer.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    self.sink.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```

This is assuming a pipeline, where data is fed into a muxer, and finally to the filesink. In a C application works, but the threading model is slightly different.

One thing to note, is that this code is executed from a callback external to the GStreamer pipeline, which has access to GStreamer pipeline elements. Is it wrong to be requesting state changes outside of the "official GStreamer pipeline"? Is it undefined to have another thread alter state?

At one point, I put a while loop in said thread to wait for the state to change on the element and it never did.

If this is wrong, is there some documentation that shows me why this is wrong, or how to do it in a way that isn't extremely cumbersome? It works fine in the C program, it's just that there's a GLib thread executing the callback as opposed to a Python thread. The pattern there is the same, set state to NULL, set file sink location, set state to PLAYING.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: set pipeline state to GST_STATE_NULL solved the problem for me

Comment: But what if I dont want to pause whole pipeline? Do you think this is doable?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it in Python but in C/C++ code I would normally set the **pipeline** to `READY` state while changing the file name.

Comment: Is it really necessary to READY whole pipeline? ;/